# Create the transformation widget in Scene Kit View

Tags: ios, ios9, scenekit

I am playing with Apple's SceneKit. I found the transformation widget used in XCode's model viewer quite helpful and would like to create one in a scene kit view as well. Does anyone know if it is possible to create one? Does it exist in the SceneKit?

The transformation widget I mean was indicated by purple strokes in the following image of the model viewer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SceneKit editing environment, including that control, is provided only as part of the Xcode UI. If you'd like to lobby Apple for the inclusion of all or some of those editing features as a SceneKit API, [file a feature request](http://bugreport.apple.com). (And note that in general, Apple tends to respond better to feature requests that spell out detailed use cases.)